# Taking the derivative of e with a strange exponent

Tags: probability, statistics, derivatives

[image]

I know that the term before the e is a constant, and so the derivative of this whole thing is going to be *the whole thing* multiplied by the derivative of the exponent.

The trouble I am having is with the derivative of the exponent.

I think it is

$\frac{-2(x-mu)*2σ^2}{4σ^4}$

Am I right here? And then the overall derivative would just be the original function multiplied by that expression above?

Comment: seems all right.

Comment: This is correct - but why bother multiplying both numerator and denominator by the constant $2 \sigma^2$? Just treat the denominator as the constant it is.

Comment: Looks like a correct application of the chain rule. And just for the record, this exponent is far from "strange"! The function you have is the Gaussian/Normal distribution with average $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Would recommend reviewing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution